# centroid of a right triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, centroid

I'm asked to find the $M_x, M_y$ and the centroid of the shape created by the functions $5x/6$ and $x=6$ that has a density of $5$.

I find 
$$M_y \int_0^5 \frac{5}{6} x^2dx = \left. \frac{5}{18} x^3 \right|_0^5 = \frac{625}{18}.$$ With density it's $M_y = 3125/18$.

I find
$$
M_x \int_0^5 \frac{\rho}{2} \times \frac{25}{36} x^2 dx
  = \left. \frac{25\rho}{216} x^3 \right|_0^5 = \frac{3125}{216} \times \rho
  = \frac{15625}{216}. 
$$
Now
$$\bar{X} = \frac{M_y}{15\rho} = \frac{125}{54}$$
and
$$\bar{Y} = \frac{M_x}{15\rho} = \frac{625}{648}.$$

The only problem is that none of those answers are right. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total mass is given by
$$
\int_0^6 \frac{5x}{6} \cdot 5 dx = 75
$$

Now for the centroid
$$
M_y = \int_0^6 \frac{5x^2}{6} \cdot 5 dx = 300
$$
so $\bar{X} = 300/75 = 4$.
Can you take it from here?